# Store the numericals in char array into an INTEGER variable in VC++.

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, char

My scenario is as follows:(C++)

In char a[10],   the array a[] has elements (numbers) like '1','2','3' etc....

Say a[0] = '1';
a[1] = '2';
a[2] = '3';

Now a[] is storing 3 characters '1', '2' and '3'. **I want to store this into an int as 123 (An integer 123).**

How to achieve this in C++ ?

Comment: There is literally tons of stuff on string to int conversions all over SO and the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a[3] = 0` is a must. If your string isn't null-terminated, most methods won't work.

After that, it's a simple `number = atoi(a)`

Comment: So, does it mean if I do a[3] = '\0'; explicitly then, i can simply assign "int number = atoi(a); ?

Comment: Exactly. atoi() converts up to the first nul.

Comment: atoi() converts up to the first non digit (excluding any preceding whitespace and +/-)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what the value after a[2] is...

```
int total = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < a[i]; i++ ) {
    total *= 10;
    total += a[i] - '0';
}
```

Comment: Which is why I said, 'Depending on what the value after a[2] is'

Comment: Yes, but `i < a[i]` does look extremely strange (it would be correct for 0-terminated arrays, though, didn't notice that originally).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

int array2int(char a[]) {
  int i = 0;
  int value = 0;
  while (a[i]) {
    value *= 10; 
    value += a[i] - '0';
    i++;
  }
  return value;
};

int main(void) {
  char a[10] = "123";
  int value = array2int(a);
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
int ca2int(char *array, size_t len){
    int v = 0;
    while(len--)
        v = 10*v + *array++ - '0';
    return v;
}

int main(){
    char a[10];
    a[0] = '1';
    a[1] = '2';
    a[2] = '3';

    std::cout << ca2int(a, 3);
}
```