# Store numericals in TCHAR array into an INTEGER variable in VC++. (in UNICODE environment)

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, char, tchar

I had asked a question very much similar to this in the thread:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259474/store-the-numericals-in-char-array-into-an-integer-variable-in-vc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259474/store-the-numericals-in-char-array-into-an-integer-variable-in-vc,)

W.R.T. the above thread, my question is as follows:: I am working in UNICODE environment. So TCHAr would probably be treated as wchar.

My scenario is as follows:(C++)

> In **TCHAR** a[10], the array a[] has elements (numbers) like
>   '1','2','3' etc....
>
> Say a[0] = '1'; a[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259474/store-the-numericals-in-char-array-into-an-integer-variable-in-vc,) = '2'; a[2] = '3';
>
> Now a[] is storing 3 characters '1', '2' and '3'. I want to store this
>   into an int as 123 (An integer 123).
>
> How to achieve this in C++ ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to null-terminate your string. Otherwise, how do you know where to stop? Then there's a function `_ttoi()` specifically for that.

```
a[3] = 0;
int n = _ttoi[a];
```

You have to understand the null termination bit. Depending on how do you fill the `a` with characters (digits), the logic of determining the end of the string might vary.

Comment: So if I do a[3] = '\0';  will I be able to use _ttoi() ?

Comment: Yes. `_ttoi` expects a null terminated string. The way you show your string, it's completely unknown what is in a[3], a[4] and so forth. Depending on how you got this string (which you don't tell), it may already be null terminated. I just wanted to make sure.